# How do I sleep every N iterations in a Javascript loop?

Tags: javascript

I currently have a Javascript forEach() loop, but I need change my code to add a "sleep" every 500th iteration.

This pattern lets me sleep for 3 seconds *every* iteration:

[How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop/3583740)

```
for (let i=1; i<10; i++) {
    setTimeout( function timer(){
        alert("hello world");
    }, i*3000 );
}
```

How can I sleep for every 2nd - or every 500th - iteration?

PS:

The solution needs to run on Chrome and IE11.

Comment: `if ((i+1) % iterationCount === 0) { /* sleep */ }`?

Comment: of course, that won't prevent the for loop from continuing to execute - asynchronous code remains asynchronous

Comment: Use `Math.floor(i / 500) * 3000` for the delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function that captures a looping variable in a closure and returns a simple function with a loop that returns on batch sizes. The effect is that it lets you continues the for loop where you left off. If you have it return a boolean indicating whether or not it's done you can wrap the whole thing in a `setInterval`. Easier to show than explain:

```js
function batch(batch_size, end){
    var i = 0                                  // capture i in closure
    return function(){
        for(i; i <= end; i++){
            console.log("doing something", i)  // work goes here
            if (!((i+1) % batch_size)) return i++
        }
        return false
    }
}
var f = batch(5, 11)                           // 0 - 11 batched in groups of 5
if (f()){                                      // start immediately, then setInterval if not finished in one batch.
    var interval = setInterval(() => {
    f() ||  clearInterval(interval)
    }, 2000 )
}
```

Comment: I like the solution.  I'm curious why the lack of semicolons :(  Full Disclosure: Personally, I'm an "always use braces" kind of guy...

Comment: @paulsm4 it's a matter of style on the semicolons. They aren't needed in most situations and I think JS is easier on the eyes without them (maybe that's my python upbringing). I wouldn't go to the mat on it though — there are good arguments for always using them.

Answer (score 3):

A recursive timeout solution:

```
const processInBatches = (array, limit, processFn, timeout) => {
    const batch = array.slice(0, limit);
    if(!batch.length) {
        return;
    }
    batch.forEach(processFn);
    const rest = array.slice(limit);
    setTimeout(() => processInBatches(rest, limit, processFn, timeout), timeout);
}

const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
processInBatches(array, 2, (x) => console.log('processing',x), 1000);
```

Comment: good point, although ambiguous based on the question if a cumulative value needs to be returned eventually

Comment: IE11 does not support shorthand function definition though. If you are going to use a transpiler, well then use async + promises as well.